# Caps Lock does not capitalize accented letters on AZERTY keyboard

Tags: gnome, keyboard, 23.10, capslock

I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 23.10 and my <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key does not work as it is supposed to. Before the update, when CAPS LOCK was on, I could get capital accented letters by just hitting <kbd>é</kbd>, <kbd>à</kbd>, <kbd>ç</kbd>, etc. keys.

I've tried each and every option in GNOME Tweaks and none of does the job.

On Ubuntu 22.04, the behaviour for CAPS LOCK is "deactivated" (default). And the default behaviour is to have capital accented letters accessible via CAPS LOCK. It's not the case anymore on 23.10.
Option to have CAPS LOCK work as SHIFT LOCK works fine (but it's definitely not the behaviour I want, I hate this stupid Windows non sense).

My keyboard works perfectly on 22.04, so it's not the source of the issue.

Has anything changed in 23.10? Is there at least a way to get the default CAPS LOCK behaviour back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have exactly the same issue. Italian keyboard layout, using Ubuntu 23.10.1 on Thinkpad T14s.

[Comment #17](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/2035076/comments/17) in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/2035076) says that there is a fix that needs some testing before it gets released. So, if all goes well, it should be out soon.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not find this bug in search engine...
I guess I can wait 1 week for Mutter 45.2-0ubuntu3 to be released.

Comment: Mutter has been updated recently so the problem is now fixed. Thanks again for pointing out the bug on Launchpad!